# avoid Circular import in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, python-import

I have two models Company and Actions:

```
from companies.models import Company

class Action(models.Model):

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True, related_name='activity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have then an utility in utils.py

```
from .models import Action

def create_action(user, verb, target_name=None, target=None):
    action = Action(user=user, verb=verb, target=target)
```

This utility I called in Company model on `def save`, so on Company Model I have:

```
from not.utils import create_action
```

so Action Model import Company Model as FK, utils import Action Model, and Company Model import utils

Now, because of circular import Django gives an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Company'
```

I saw some q/a here to use import directly (without from) I tried but didn't worked

```
import not.utils as nt
nt.create_action(...)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the `Company` import from `actions/models.py` and [use a string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) instead:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', blank=True, null=True, related_name='activity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: In the official Django documentation they use exactly this notion. This is the proper way of assigning relations.